# Could Targeted Tags Help Here?

Tags: discussion

On another SE I'm on, I found this Meta Question:

https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/lets-drum-up-some-content-whos-up-for-community-projects

I would think it could work here as well, but wonder how we could go about doing it? I'm not exactly sure a community project would be of great assistance, but we could target a tag and ask questions towards that tag or whatever.

Thoughts? Concerns?

Let's get this place built.

Comment: That's an interesting idea....

Comment: Yes! I'l let this brew in my head for a bit

Comment: I still like this idea